# How do I apply code to multiple fieldsets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to check/uncheck a specific set of checkboxes

```js
var $allergies = $('.allergies .gchoice:not(:first-child) .gfield-choice-input')

$('.allergies .gchoice:first-child .gfield-choice-input').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $allergies.prop('checked', false)
    }
});

$allergies.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.allergies .gchoice:first-child .gfield-choice-input').prop('checked', false)
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="allergies">
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.1" type="checkbox" value="No Allergies" checked="checked" id="choice_2_20_1">
        <label for="choice_2_20_1" id="label_2_20_1">No Allergies</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_2">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.2" type="checkbox" value="Beef" id="choice_2_20_2">
        <label for="choice_2_20_2" id="label_2_20_2">Beef</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_3">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.3" type="checkbox" value="Chicken" id="choice_2_20_3">
        <label for="choice_2_20_3" id="label_2_20_3">Chicken</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_4">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.4" type="checkbox" value="Dairy" id="choice_2_20_4">
        <label for="choice_2_20_4" id="label_2_20_4">Dairy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_5">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.5" type="checkbox" value="Fish" id="choice_2_20_5">
        <label for="choice_2_20_5" id="label_2_20_5">Fish</label>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="conditions">
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.1" type="checkbox" value="No Conditions" checked="checked"
            id="choice_2_18_1">
        <label for="choice_2_18_1" id="label_2_18_1">No Conditions</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_2">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.2" type="checkbox" value="Anxiety" id="choice_2_18_2">
        <label for="choice_2_18_2" id="label_2_18_2">Anxiety</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_3">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.3" type="checkbox" value="Arthritis" id="choice_2_18_3">
        <label for="choice_2_18_3" id="label_2_18_3">Arthritis</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_4">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.4" type="checkbox" value="Cancer" id="choice_2_18_4">
        <label for="choice_2_18_4" id="label_2_18_4">Cancer</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_5">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.5" type="checkbox" value="Cataracts" id="choice_2_18_5">
        <label for="choice_2_18_5" id="label_2_18_5">Cataracts</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

but now I have another set of checkboxes that I want to apply the code to called Conditions

How can I modify the code so that it applies to Allergies OR Conditions without having to duplicate it.

Comment: Why do you even need the 'No allergies' and 'No conditions' options? Surely the fact that if none of the boxes are ticked, that implies the 'none' option...? Including those options just makes your UI more confusing for users, and needlessly complicated to build. Eg. you can uncheck all boxes, including 'none'.

Comment: Write a function that takes the first part of your selector (`.allergies`) as a parameter, and then insert it dynamically into the selector strings you are using, or pass it as the second parameter for `$()`, to use it as _context_ for the selection.

Comment: Agreed but those boxes represent an affirmative selection and have been added per instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be:

```js
function checkboxGroup(checkboxes) {
  const master = checkboxes.first();   // get jQuery collection of the first one
  const slaves = checkboxes.slice(1);  // get jQuery collection of all others
  
  master.change(untick(slaves));
  slaves.change(untick(master));
}

function untick(checkboxes) {
  return () => {                       // returning a lambda here as event handler
    checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
  };
}

/* --- */

const $allergies = $('.allergies input');
const $conditions = $('.conditions input');

checkboxGroup($allergies);
checkboxGroup($conditions);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="allergies">
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.1" type="checkbox" value="No Allergies" checked="checked" id="choice_2_20_1">
        <label for="choice_2_20_1" id="label_2_20_1">No Allergies</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_2">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.2" type="checkbox" value="Beef" id="choice_2_20_2">
        <label for="choice_2_20_2" id="label_2_20_2">Beef</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_3">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.3" type="checkbox" value="Chicken" id="choice_2_20_3">
        <label for="choice_2_20_3" id="label_2_20_3">Chicken</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_4">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.4" type="checkbox" value="Dairy" id="choice_2_20_4">
        <label for="choice_2_20_4" id="label_2_20_4">Dairy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_5">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.5" type="checkbox" value="Fish" id="choice_2_20_5">
        <label for="choice_2_20_5" id="label_2_20_5">Fish</label>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="conditions">
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.1" type="checkbox" value="No Conditions" checked="checked"
            id="choice_2_18_1">
        <label for="choice_2_18_1" id="label_2_18_1">No Conditions</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_2">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.2" type="checkbox" value="Anxiety" id="choice_2_18_2">
        <label for="choice_2_18_2" id="label_2_18_2">Anxiety</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_3">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.3" type="checkbox" value="Arthritis" id="choice_2_18_3">
        <label for="choice_2_18_3" id="label_2_18_3">Arthritis</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_4">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.4" type="checkbox" value="Cancer" id="choice_2_18_4">
        <label for="choice_2_18_4" id="label_2_18_4">Cancer</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_5">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.5" type="checkbox" value="Cataracts" id="choice_2_18_5">
        <label for="choice_2_18_5" id="label_2_18_5">Cataracts</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can make it more generic by marking the `.allergies` and `.conditions` elements up via a separate CSS-class that you'd use to select elements the contain checkbox groups:

```js
function checkboxGroup(checkboxes) {
  const master = checkboxes.first();   // get jQuery collection of the first one
  const slaves = checkboxes.slice(1);  // get jQuery collection of all others
  
  master.change(untick(slaves));
  slaves.change(untick(master));
}

function untick(checkboxes) {
  return () => {                       // returning a lambda here as event handler
    checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
  };
}

/* --- */

const $checkboxGroups = $('.checkboxgroup').toArray();
$checkboxGroups.forEach((group) => {
   checkboxGroup($('input', group));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="allergies checkboxgroup">
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.1" type="checkbox" value="No Allergies" checked="checked" id="choice_2_20_1">
        <label for="choice_2_20_1" id="label_2_20_1">No Allergies</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_2">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.2" type="checkbox" value="Beef" id="choice_2_20_2">
        <label for="choice_2_20_2" id="label_2_20_2">Beef</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_3">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.3" type="checkbox" value="Chicken" id="choice_2_20_3">
        <label for="choice_2_20_3" id="label_2_20_3">Chicken</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_4">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.4" type="checkbox" value="Dairy" id="choice_2_20_4">
        <label for="choice_2_20_4" id="label_2_20_4">Dairy</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_20_5">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_20.5" type="checkbox" value="Fish" id="choice_2_20_5">
        <label for="choice_2_20_5" id="label_2_20_5">Fish</label>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="conditions checkboxgroup">
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_1">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.1" type="checkbox" value="No Conditions" checked="checked"
            id="choice_2_18_1">
        <label for="choice_2_18_1" id="label_2_18_1">No Conditions</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_2">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.2" type="checkbox" value="Anxiety" id="choice_2_18_2">
        <label for="choice_2_18_2" id="label_2_18_2">Anxiety</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_3">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.3" type="checkbox" value="Arthritis" id="choice_2_18_3">
        <label for="choice_2_18_3" id="label_2_18_3">Arthritis</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_4">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.4" type="checkbox" value="Cancer" id="choice_2_18_4">
        <label for="choice_2_18_4" id="label_2_18_4">Cancer</label>
    </div>
    <div class="gchoice gchoice_2_18_5">
        <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_18.5" type="checkbox" value="Cataracts" id="choice_2_18_5">
        <label for="choice_2_18_5" id="label_2_18_5">Cataracts</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

*EDIT*

Aside from that, your use of CSS-classes looks a bit "weird", because you are using them as if they were IDs (referring to `gchoice_2_20_1`, `gchoice_2_20_2`, etc.). I cannot say if they are *necessary* or if you *have to* use them like this. Just wanted to mention it.

Comment: +1 You can do the loop even shorter in jQuery notation: `$('.checkboxgroup').each((_,grp)=>checkboxGroup($('input',grp)));`

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet, it works good.